# How to run a main application (not a spring boots appl) from a folder of Spring Boot application as jar

Tags: java

Background:
I have written a one-time tool to run as a non-spring boot application in one of the folder of Spring Boots. This tool calls a class from Spring boots application.

I tried :
`java -jar <jarName> <com.dummy.folder3.Mainpgm1> -u <username> -p <password>`

This when calls spring boots class fails with "Invalid parameters; exiting without generation"

Folder structure:

```
com/
  dummy/
   <folder1>
   <folder2>
   <folder3>
      Mainpgm1
   Application
```

Any help

Answer (score 0):

java -jar xxx.jar --username=xxx --passwd=xxx

```
@Compoment
public class Test {

    @Value("username")
    private String username;

    @Value("passwd")
    private String passwd;

}
```